# My Pc suddenly had Bootmgr missing following up with a "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, bios

Hi guys I today started up my pc today(like any other day) and suddenly on desktop my pc freezes completely ctrl+alt+del doesn't work.

So I restarted my pc and suddenly it gave me the bootmgr is missing error, I then unplugged my ext hdd(not that it normally gave me issues) to then get the next issue which is "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key".

I have no idea where this issue came from, it's all so sudden.

What I did so far is:

Restart it a few times.
Check my bios for the boot priority(My SSD is all of a sudden missing) only my disk drive is detectable.
Noticed my Bios build is 1107, My motherboard is the Asus P8H67M-Pro, went to the site and saw the latest build 1502 so it's quite outdated although it doesn't reach windows since my ssd is missing so I can't safe start to update my bios.

My SSD is by the way not new, I didn't add anything to my pc external nor internal and my SSD brand is OCZ Vertex 4 120gb. Also I opened up my pc because I read my ssd should be on the sata 0 but I don't see any numbers on the cables for I'm also uncertain which it needs plugged in.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is everything plugged in correctly? Things can come loose. Any way, this sounds like the Hard Drive is old/dead, if you can, run a Smart tool

Comment: My SSD Is not even a year old how could it be dead already?

And I mean it was working yesterday with no issues.

Comment: Also how can I confirm everything is plugged in right?

Comment: Agreed with @DaveRook - It may be the drive. However, it could also be the headers on your motherboard (or the mobo in general, though less likely) or the sata cable.  So I would try other cables and other headers.  After that, assuming the bios recognizes it - I would boot a live linux disc, recover your stuff, and fresh install (if possible).

Comment: But how could this all have happened out of nowhere??

Comment: Unfortunately, SSDs are known to work perfectly until they don't work at all. (It's one of their two main failings, the other being the gradual degredation with use, the impact of which can be debated but it's a fact that it's there.) From what you have written, it does sound to me like the SSD might have gone to data heaven, unfortunately. I'd try to plug it into another computer and see if it comes to life and your files are there. If it doesn't, I'm afraid you may be in the market for a replacement and a backup restore.

Comment: I don't have another computer to plug it into..and as far as I know I bought a Sata 3 cable back when I bought the ssd so I think there is only one possible way to hook it up? So it can't be wrong? Not sure though but are you serious in less then a year I need to buy a new one? That can't be so..

Comment: Based on the OP's comments, this is a disk failure. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Your boot file in windows gone corrupt, you have to insert cd to recover boot files, or probably you need to reinstall windows.

Comment: But my SSD isn't showing in the priority window. So it's not rigged I guess? It's windows? I entered a windows 8 boot cd and it's running can i hereby confirm my SSD isn't dead?

Comment: Sir, I've tried to reinstall windows and it won't recover anything because my ssd is undetectable. Is there any other solution?